# Access to shared printer for ASP.NET Core hosted in IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stimulsoft

Can anybody give me a solution for accessing to shared printer like: "\192.168.30.139\HPPrinter" via ASP.NET Core application. I used "Stimulsoft" for print my document directly for C# code, if I have to give permission or etc... how can I do that?
I am remined my code is working on local system (Visual Studio or local IIS) but when I publish my project (ASP.NET Core) it doesn't work and *throw below error message*:
**"Settings to access printer. '\192.168.30.139\HPPrinter' are not valid."**
My server is on local network and can browse "\192.168.30.139\HPPrinter" address well.

```
StiReport report = new StiReport(); 
report.Load(".mrt file template");

report.RegData("CardTable", new { // My Data });

PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
settings.PrinterName = @"\\192.168.30.139\HPPrinter";

report.Print(false, settings); // => "I get error at this line"
```

Comment: Printing from server in a web app is unusual. You could redesign your app so that the server creates a PDF and returns it to the browser which then sends the data to the printer.

Comment: Yes I know but I want design my site to print some cards by clicking on records, because my data is sensitive and I can not create pdf from my data.

Comment: What if someone prints and then scans to pdf by themselves? You can't prevent that. As for the issue, I'd start by learning what protocol and port are used, could be a firewall issue.

Comment: We will print data on card and when someone scan the card they can not use them.